# Is top-left-corner for VT100 0,0 or 1,1?

Tags: vt100

I wrote/maintain a terminal emulator called ucon (http://www.umonfw.com/ucon).  I suppose calling it an actual terminal emulator is sad because although it does a lot of good stuff, its not very good at dealing with the VT100 escape sequences.  Anyway, one issue I've never resolved is the actual coordinate position of the top-left-corner (TLC). For quite some time now I've assumed that 1,1 is the TLC (that's what VI seems to use); however, there are several cases where it appears that 0,0 is the TLC.  Plus I do occasionally see programs actually use the escape sequence "<1b>[0;0f"  which forces the cursor to position 0,0; hence, if we assume the cursor is not intentionally being placed off screen, one would have to assume that 0,0 is the TLC.... ????

Anyone out there a VT100 guru?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top left corner is 1,1 according the [ANSI X3.64 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). The value of zero represents the default value. And the TLC is the default in this case.

Comment: Yea, that's what I have as the default now; however, I have seen applications use 0,0; so I built logic into the code so that if that is seen, then I adjust the emulation to assume 0,0 is the origin.  That seems to work out best.